# Jsoup parse web and splite the value from parsing data

Tags: java, android

I use Jsoup for parsing web data , my code like this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.nt-movie.com.tw/showtime.php").get();

Elements elements=document.select("li");

for (Element elementTime : elements){
                    String time=elementTime.getElementsByClass("times gray33").text();
                    String spiltTime[]=time.split("");
                    Log.d("time",spiltTime.toString());
                }
```

When i haven't split time , it show like the photo:
[image]
I try to split time , it becomes to...
[image]

I want to let it shows like:

10:00

11:00

12:10

.
.
.

My question is that do i split time successfully or not ? Any help would be grateful, thanks.

Comment: thanks @Misha , i can see the value now.

Comment: Please do mention the problem statement in question.